# GCC / G++ path include flags starts with '='

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, gnu

I tried to write platform-independent build file (for ninja) and try to avoid specifying the full paths such as `D:/tools/x64/msys2/ucrt64/include/librsvg-2.0` or `/usr/include/librsvg-2.0`.

GCC docs say that

> If dir begins with ‘=’ or $SYSROOT, then the ‘=’ or $SYSROOT is
> replaced by the sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot.

But on Windows with MSYS2 environment when I set flags like `-I=librsvg-2.0` or `-I=/librsvg-2.0` it has no effect. Can it be MSYS2 only behaviour, or I do something wrong?

Comment: You generate ninja files, you don’t write them. Use a build system like cmake or meson.

Comment: I'm using librsvg and it doesn't have CMake support, so I just need to specify -I relative to the system include directory.

Comment: There is an unofficial vcpkg librsvg package, but I don't want to use it - it has an outdated version and vcpkg is pretty monstrous for my simple project. And question point is to understand how does that flag works.

Comment: While we're going down this road, it doesn't really support ninja, either. You `./configure && make && make install` the library. But that's beside the point of my **comment** that you don't write ninja files. And that's not my personal opinion, it's how the tool is designed. Closer to your point, the doc you quote has two options; did you try the other? I ask because `-I=` looks completely bogus. And also because the doc you quote is offering a potential solution but nobody here can say if you tried it.

Comment: My project compiles with just a few `-I` include flags. All I need at the moment is to specify these flags without system dependent paths. Everything works when I specify full paths, but I try to avoid. I just want to understand how the `=` works in the `-I` flags for GCC compilers.
At the moment I can build this project with just one `g++` command, even without make or ninja. Ninja build files are much simpler and dumber than make files, and no configuration is required here because this is just a prototype in which I try out the library functions.

Comment: Try `-I==librsvg2.0`.  If that works, I will explain.

Comment: No, solution was to set `--sysroot=your_path`, and then `-I=librsvg-2.0` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, GCC has own system include paths, but it doesn't have the default $SYSROOT value. So first you need to set it using the `--sysroot=your_path` flag, if you want use `-I=`.